# VCard 4.0 Phones Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0, vcf-vcard

I want to read VCard 4.0 file .

I use this sample.

but when I use this solution for this file.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Gump;Forrest;;;
FN: Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212
TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212
ADR;TYPE=work;LABEL="42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America"
 :;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

it doesn't find Phone parameter - for example, I use this Regex for a phone number:

```
 RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace;
    regex = new Regex(@"(\n(?<strElement>(TEL)) (;*(?<strAttr>(HOME|WORK)))* (;(?<strType>(VOICE|CELL|PAGER|MSG|FAX)))*  (;(?<strPref>(PREF)))* (;[^:]*)*  (:(?<strValue>[^\n\r]*)))", options);


 mc = regex.Matches(s);
            if (mc.Count > 0)
            {
                Phones = new Phone[mc.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
                {
                    m = mc[i];
                    Phones[i].number = m.Groups["strValue"].Value;
                    ss = m.Groups["strAttr"].Value;
                    if (ss == "HOME")
                        Phones[i].homeWorkType = HomeWorkType.home;
                    else if (ss == "WORK")
                        Phones[i].homeWorkType = HomeWorkType.work;

                    if (m.Groups["strPref"].Value == "PREF")
                        Phones[i].pref = true;

                    ss = m.Groups["strType"].Value;
                    if (ss == "VOICE")
                        Phones[i].phoneType = PhoneType.VOICE;
                    else if (ss == "CELL")
                        Phones[i].phoneType = PhoneType.CELL;
                    else if (ss == "PAGER")
                        Phones[i].phoneType = PhoneType.PAGER;
                    else if (ss == "MSG")
                        Phones[i].phoneType = PhoneType.MSG;
                    else if (ss == "FAX")
                        Phones[i].phoneType = PhoneType.FAX;


                }
            }
```

but value of strAttr,strType in empty.

How to set Regex for these?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regular expression try vCard Class Library, I found it on google:

http://www.thoughtproject.com/Libraries/vCard/index.htm